# add value to a field from CSV file in a database

Tags: php, sql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a table with 2 fields, Email and Date

Now I have imported the emails from a CSV file but they are just the Email usernames eg. ShaneL

There are over 500 entries. And I must add @test.co.za to each one.

Is there no SQL that I could run in order to add that text onto each row in the database table?

Comment: I made an edit to the question/tags, however this line *"Is there no sql i could run to add that text onto each line?"* I don't quite understand and others may not neither. Did you mean "append that text onto each row's value in the database"? rather than in the file?

Comment: as simplistic as my above comment may sound to you, you would be suprised as to how may take this question. I haven't gotten a response from what I thought was a valid point/question. Do I have to post an answer in order to get a reply?

Comment: my mistake. sorry about that. was abit busy. I needed to add a piece of text into each row value on a table in the database. I had already imported the data. It was just mixed up abit and missing the @test.co.za behind each email username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use update

assuming your column in named  email

```
update your_table 
set email = concat(email , '@test.co.za')
```

and for space you could use replace

```
update your_table 
set email = concat(replace(email, ' ', '') , '@test.co.za')
```

Comment: ty so much :) that worked perfectly. Is there a similar command to remove any spaces? Because I see some email usernames were split eg. Shane Naidoo instead of ShaneNaidoo

Comment: Your a legend sir! Will select this as answer as soon it allows me to

Comment: I know how to sir it just says i have to wait a few minutes before I am allowed to

Comment: Just something for me to know sir, if i wanted to move everything thats after the space into another field say 'Extra'. Would that be possible? for example. If the email field has: Shane Naidoo. Then it would move Naidoo to the Extra table field

Comment: @RedZ ^ that's another question. If the answerer wants to build that, it's up to them. But then your question as posted will not reflect the new question.

Comment: I understand sir. Would making a new question be the correct way around this sir?

Comment: @RedZ Yes it would make more sense and that's pretty much how Stack works.

Comment: @Fred-ii- my apologese. Just something I wanted to know extra. I will post it now :) Thank you so much

Comment: @RedZ So why are you asking someone else to do it? under the other answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just thought it would be easier then setting a whole new question sir. I am still learning MYSQL Functions. But I was able to get it to work now. RiggsFolly gave me a link with a lot of information about MYSQL functions.

Comment: @RedZ I can understand that it would, but when you add/ask more "after the fact", then the question becomes unclear/too broad. Future visitors would have to go over the comments/edited answer(s) in order to see what the whole story was about. I know it can be next to impossible to know the results ahead of time from something that may have come as a surprise, but this too is a "surprise". Just something for you to think about. We like to help, but when things start to go from one problem to another, the load starts to be a bit heavy.

Comment: understandable sir @Fred-ii- i will keep that in mind.

Comment: As  suggest by Fred -ii-  is alway better post  a new properly described  question and not change an answer  question.  so post the new one and eventually comment me the related  link

Comment: @scaisEdge http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834952/phpmyadmin-move-text-from-one-field-to-another/42835182?noredirect=1#comment72780581_42835182 but I was able to fix the issue myself :)

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE your_table SET email = CONCAT(email, '@test.co.za');
```

Comment: ty so much :) that worked perfectly. Is there a similar command to remove any spaces? Because I see some email usernames were split eg. Shane Naidoo instead of ShaneNaidoo

Comment: UPDATE your_table SET email = REPLACE(email, ' ', '');