# phpmyadmin move text from one field to another

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have a table with 2 fields. Email, Extra

Every entry in the email field has a name then a space and then surname. eg. Ravi Naidoo

Is there a SQL query that I would be able to run that would move the surname to the Extra Table field and then remove it from the Email field along with the space?

```
Eg. Email field: Ravi Naidoo
```

after the change would be

```
Email field: Ravi
Extra field: Naidoo
```

I know that this query removes the space:

```
UPDATE your_table SET email = REPLACE(email, ' ', '')
```

But am unsure how to move the surname text to the Extra field at the same time.

Comment: Not a command, you just have to write a query

Comment: my apologese i meant query. I will fix the question @RiggsFolly

Comment: Ok, but the idea here is.... You write the query, You test the query.... If you cannot get the query to work, you ask us for help at that stage. **We do not write the query for you**

Comment: I edited my attempt sir. @RiggsFolly

Comment: That will just remove the space from the email column and then you are skuppered because you will not be able to distinguish first name from last name any more

Comment: exactly sir. I am not sure how to move the text to another field. I am currently studying this in class and am just practising at the moment and taking notes. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Well ignore the answer given and read up on [MYSQL String Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) and develop your own solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table 
    SET extra = substring_index(email, ' ', -1), 
        email = substring_index(email,' ',1);
```

Comment: ty but this didnt work, It just copied all of it into Extra

Comment: I found the fix sir. With your query the extra part must be passed first then the Email part. Then it works.

Comment: @RedZ Just to be clear; was the edit made to the answer the final solution that was used?

Comment: @RedZ Cool, glad to hear it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider you string is like

```
$user="bikash@gmail.com Bikash Chhualsingh";
```

Separate the values.

```
$user_arr=explode(' ', $user, 2);
```

Now you can run the Sql

```
"UPDATE table_name
SET email = ".$user_arr[0].", Extra = ".$user_arr[1]." WHERE id=5;
```

Have a nice day :)