# finding duplicates in 2 phpmyadmin Columns

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have a table with 2 fields . Name and Surname

Now I imported a CSV document and some of the data got mismatched and it copied the name into the surname field.

So I need to run a query to find any rows that are duplicates

eg. Name: John   Surname: John

I am currently learning about SQL Fuctions and have attempted a few queries but I am only able to check a single field for duplicates.

Comment: What is the difference between his question and [this question where you accepted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834952/phpmyadmin-move-text-from-one-field-to-another)

Comment: I would be tempted to 1) drop this table. 2) Fix your csv file 3) import the fixed data

Comment: the query i asked before sir was to add/edit the data within the fields in that question :) Thanx to the answer below i am sorted sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `name_table` WHERE `Name` = `Surname`
```

Comment: ty sir that is correct but I worked out the code. WIll mark your answer as correct though :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT name = surname FROM table_name;`

It will return '1' for the fields with same name and surname.

Comment: it brought forward just alot of 0's so I dont think this is working, If i look at the table I can see the duplicates but this query doesnt find them

Comment: with 'name' and 'surname', I meant column_names you want to check in a row. `SELECT column_name_1 = column_name_2 FROM table_name;`